# Is it possible to time the amount of seconds between users joining?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I want to add a feature for my Discord bot that prevents raids and self-bots. The title briefly specifies my question.

What I want to do is when a user joins my guild, I want the bot to initiate a timer and it begins counting down, so it basically alternates and the timer stops when the next user joins.

When the timer stops, it will determine that if the interval was 7 seconds or less, it will assign them the **Restricted Access** role and request all of the offending accounts to complete a CAPTCHA to continue. However, if the interval was 8 seconds or more, it will leave them unaffected.

All I will require is a concept of how I could accomplish this such as libraries I might want, any additional details is unnecessary.

Comment: You might want to check out the guidelines. Your question as posed is likely to be closed as off-topic since you are explicitly requesting things like library recommendations, and your question is pretty vague in general. Might be worth trying to narrow it down to one or more specific technical questions (eg: I am using library X to accomplish Y. I tried Z but it does A instead of B as expected.).

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable lets say `lastJoinedTime`

then use this:

```
client.on(`guildMemberAdd`,function(){
   if(Date.now()-8000 < lastJoinedTime){//if the last join was less than 8 secs ago
       //Restrict em
   }
   else {
       //They are fine
   }
   lastJoinedTime = Date.now();
});
```

another way of checking it is:

```
if(Date.now()-lastJoinedTime > 8000){}//if last join was less than 8 secs ago.
```